# Nested API Requests with rxjs on Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm new in rxjs and after readed tons of articles I feel a bit confused.
I have a lot of nested http requests,that fetch data from the API.
First request gets the list of my devices, every device contains a list of sensors, every sensor contains a list of temperatures.
The first API request returns the devices list with sensors array filled, but the temperatures array are empty. At this point I must do one http request for each sensors to fetch temperatures data.

I tried to use switchmap combined with forkJoin, but in the observable subscription I obtain only the arrays of temperatures.
How can I fill temperatures arrays of each sensor?

```js
APIconnector.GetDevices()
    .pipe(
      tap(devices => {console.log(devices)}),
      switchMap(devices => forkJoin(devices.map(device => device.Sensors))),
      tap(sensors => {console.log(sensors)}),
      switchMap(sensors => forkJoin(sensors.map(sensor => {
        const param = {
          MinutesInterval: 30,
          StartDate: stDate,
          EndDate: new Date(),
          SensorIds: [sensor.Id]
        };  
        return APIconnector.GetIntervalRange(param);
      })))
    ).subscribe(data => {      
      console.log(data);
    })
```

I need all the data returned by the API, not only the last one.

**-- UPDATE --**

I hope this stackblitz sketch can help you.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txtemn

Comment: It would be great If you can add a stackblitz with dummy data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be a challenge to get the syntax of your example exactly correct without a stackblitz, so I'm posting one of mine that I know works and hopefully you can extrapolate from there:

```
  // All products
  products$ = this.http.get<Product[]>(this.productsUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('Products', JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );

  allProductsAndSuppliers$ = this.products$
    .pipe(
      switchMap(products => forkJoin(
        products.map(product =>
          forkJoin(product.supplierIds.map(supplierId => this.http.get<Supplier>(`${this.suppliersUrl}/${supplierId}`)))
            .pipe(
              map(suppliers => ({
                ...product,
                suppliers: suppliers
              } as Product))
            )
        ))
      )
    );
```

I broke it into two pieces:

The `products$` stream gets all of the products. It looks like you are doing something similar to get all of the devices.

I then get use the `products$` stream and get all of the suppliers for that product, defined as `allProductsAndSuppliers$`.

In the second stream, I first use `switchMap` to execute another http request for each product.

I then use `forkJoin` to re-emit the set of products as an array.

Inside the first forkJoin, I use the products array map operator to "loop" through each product. For each product, I use another `forkJoin` to find all of the suppliers and emit them as an array.

Inside the second forkJoin, I get each supplier as defined in the product's supplierIds property.

I pipe the result through a map operator that builds a `Product` containing a copy of the product and its list of suppliers.

For reference, my Product interface looks like this:

```
export interface Product {
  id: number;
  productName: string;
  productCode?: string;
  description?: string;
  supplierIds?: number[];
  suppliers?: Supplier[];
}
```

I use the set of supplierIds retrieved with the product to populate the array of suppliers.

Does this look applicable to your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are trying to do is :

```
service.getA().pipe(
   switchMap(resultA => forkJoin(of(resultA), service.getB(resultA ))),
   tap(([resultA, resultB]) => console.log({resultA,resultB}))
)
```