# How to execute another api based on first api data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am learning RxJS. I have 2 api, based on data of 1st api, I have to call second api and return the value. I did with subscribe() method like this:

```
checkPermission(permissionName: string): Observable<boolean> {
    this.checkCompanySettingForPermission(
      this.pageLevelCompanySettingName
    ).subscribe(res => {
      const shouldCheck = res.Value;
      if (shouldCheck.toLowerCase() === "true") {
        this.hasPermission(permissionName).subscribe(res => {
          this.$permissionSub.next(res.permission);
        });
      } else {
        this.$permissionSub.next(true);
      }
    });
    return this.$permissionSub.asObservable();
  }
```

I want to avoid `subscribe()` method in another `subscribe()` method. Can I do with any operator of RxJS?

I tried it with `switchMap()` also but getting lots of syntax error. Please help.

Comment: Hello! Why are you hesitant to use nested subscribe method? You can always unsubscribe when you're finished.

Comment: @AliCelebi actully my seniors want me to don't use subscribe in another subscribe, and I am trying it from last 3 hrs. But not getting solution.

Comment: Please see the following example where this type of question was asked. I hope it would be useful for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58717372/nested-api-requests-with-rxjs-on-angular

Comment: @AliCelebi tried so many things, but not getting any solution. Please help if you can. Last hope

Comment: I think you're looking for [mergeMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap)

Comment: @jabaa any supportive code please?

Comment: You can check the answer. switchMap and mergeMap are similar in your case.

Comment: @jabaa which answer? posted by Amer Yousuf ?

Comment: Yes, my answer would be pretty similar.

Comment: @jabaa But I am getting an error, I replied my error in his answer

Comment: As far as I understand your task in your job is to learn about Rxjs and not to get a ready code from the internet. You got names for 2 operators and a (not completely correct) code snippet. You should be able to find a solution with it. Run the code in a debugger and fix the error

Comment: @jabaa I am debugging his solution, trying it, but not getting the actual reason, because it is working when  if (shouldCheck.toLowerCase() === 'true') , otherwise giving me an error

Comment: The most important tool for a developer is the debugger. With your debugger you would immediately see the missing return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using one of the Higher-Order `RxJS` mapping operators such as: [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap), [mergeMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap), [concatMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/concatMap), merge the `source` observable with the new one.

So if we go with `switchMap` or `mergeMap` in your case we should return at the end a new observable to be merged with the original one `checkCompanySettingForPermission`.

If the condition is true, will return the `this.hasPermission` observable, else will return a new observable using `of` function with the value we need to pass (`true` in your case).

You can try the following:

```js
checkPermission(permissionName: string): Observable<boolean> {
  this.checkCompanySettingForPermission(this.pageLevelCompanySettingName)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(res => {
        const shouldCheck = res.Value;
        if (shouldCheck.toLowerCase() === 'true') {
          // switchMap to the new observable, then map it to return only the permission.
          return this.hasPermission(permissionName).pipe(
            tap(result => {
              // do some stuff with the result before mapping it to the `result.permission`
            }),
            map(result => result.permission)
          );
        } else {
          // return observable of true, to be handled within subscribe.
          return of(true);
        }
      })
    )
    .subscribe(permission => this.$permissionSub.next(permission));

  return this.$permissionSub.asObservable();
}
```

And if you don't use the `this.$permissionSub` elsewhere, you can remove it from the method above, and `return this.checkCompanySettingForPermission(....)` without `subscribe`, then you can call this method in your component like the following:

```js
// Example
this.service.checkPermission(addPermission).subscribe((value) => {
   console.log(value)
})
```

Comment: getting error => You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Comment: I think It should work, please check it again.

Comment: I am debugging your solution, trying it, but not getting the actual reason, because it is working when " if (shouldCheck.toLowerCase() === 'true')" , otherwise giving me an error

Comment: Sorry, my bad, just add `return` before `of(true)`.

Comment: is there any way so that I can check result.permission value and if it is false then i can show alert message that you dont have permission?

Comment: You can do that within `map` operator. `map(result => { console.log(result); return result.permission; }`

Comment: thanks for answering, can you please explain in what we did in above answer in brief so that next time i can also imagine the same situation I can also develop such thing.

Comment: Or you can use [tap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) operator

Answer (score 0):

Try this format.

```js
checkPermission(permissionName: string): Observable<boolean> {
  this.checkCompanySettingForPermission(this.pageLevelCompanySettingName)
    .pipe(
      map(res => res?.Value.toLowerCase() === 'true'
          ? this.hasPermission(permissionName).pipe(
               map(result => result.permission)
            )
          : of(true)

       ),
      switchMap(ob => ob)
    )
    .subscribe(permission => this.$permissionSub.next(permission));

  return this.$permissionSub.asObservable();
}
```